# Web Side Login / no debug.print shown in specific Window

Tags: html, excel, internet-explorer

I want to login a web side 
After a lot of trial and errors I finally wrote a code that works pretty well.
.. but got probs
First I got a prob that occurs and said
no connection to server
This Prob I solved

Set ie = CreateObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")

The next Prob is that when I ran the code Step by step (Trigger F8) the code runs pretty well.But Triggering  F5 I got the Prob in Line 
Set UserNameInput = LoginForm.getElementsByClassName("prePopulatedCredentials")(0)
This.. I do not understand

The next Prob is a debug.print "Prob"
Although I activated the Window (STR+G) debug.print is not shown.
Why want I see the debug Print result?
So.. I want to find out which Button I have to trigger by using the VBA Code
In my case I have 3 options
Search, new Search, go back or Sign In
For Sign In I found a solution for another web Side
Sub TestLogin()
Dim...
Dim LoginForm As MSHTML.HTMLFormElement
.. code
LoginForm.submit

For another Web Side
I want to find the buttons
Search, new Search, go back

The code is almost the same

Sub Get()
Dim...
Dim HTML Button AS MSHTML.IHTMLELEMENT
... Code

Set Buttons= HTMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName("button")
For Each HTMLButton In HTMLButtons
Debug.Print HTMLButton.className, HTMLButton.tagName, HTMLButton.Id, HTMLButton.innerText
Next Button

End Sub

In this case the code runs until the line 
Set Buttons= HTMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName("button")
and it jumps over  to End Sub

Here my Code for the first web side with the Prob Triggering the code with F8 or F5

```
Sub TestLogin()

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
Sub TestLogin()
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim LoginForm As MSHTML.HTMLFormElement
Dim UserNameInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim PasswordInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

' Here I found a solution in the www regarding the Prob Net.Framework

Set ie = CreateObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")

ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate Sheet1.Range("B1").Text


Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSSTATE_COMPLETE And ie.Busy
Loop

Set doc = ie.Document

Set LoginForm = doc.getElementById(Sheet1.Range("B4").Text)
Set UserNameInput = LoginForm.getElementsByClassName("prePopulatedCredentials")(0)
Set PasswordInput = LoginForm.getElementsByClassName("prePopulatedCredentials ")(1)

UserNameInput.Value = Sheet1.Range("B2").Text
PasswordInput.Value = Sheet1.Range("B3").Text

Stop

'LoginForm.submit

End Sub
```

An here the code for the 2nd Web Side with the Prob debug Print

```
Sub Get()

Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim UserNameInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim VornameInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement

Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Dim SecurityWindow As Object

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set ie = CreateObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")


ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate Tabelle1.Range("B1").Text

Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSSTATE_COMPLETE And ie.Busy
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = ie.Document
Set UserNameInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("sur")
Set VornameInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("given")

UserNameInput.Value = Sheets1.Range("B2").Text
VornameInput.Value = Sheets1.Range("B3").Text

Stop

Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("btn")
     For Each HTMLButton In HTMLButtons
    Debug.Print HTMLButtons.className, HTMLButtons.tagName, HTMLButtons.ID,      HTMLButtons.innerText
          Next HTMLButton

End Sub
```

What have I done wrong or missed?

Thx for any help
And.. most important
Take all of you care
Best wishes, stay safe and healthy!

Pete

Comment: I suggest you do not post multiple issues in a single thread. Try to provide the relevant HTML code along with your VBA code. For your first issue: What error did you see when you press the F5 key? Try to make your code wait for some seconds to see whether it helps to fix this issue. For your second issue: I suggest you create a new thread for it.

Comment: HI deepak! Thx for your Hint ..I´m new in here Sorry  Regarding the first issue .. yes I ´ve tried this "try to make the code wait" .. and it seems that it woks Question tregarding the 2nd issue What do you think Shall we forget the first issue and go on with the 2nd Issue ? Will this be a good Idea? If Yes  I have more Information

Comment: If your first issue is resolved then I will post my suggestion as an answer. You can try to accept the answer. For your second issue, I suggest you create a new thread. The reason I am suggesting you for creating a new thread because multiple issues in a single thread will create complexity to understand the issue properly for future visitors. We can try to help you with your second issue in a new thread. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Hi Deepak,Good Plan! THX.. First Issue.. I fit in the Line  Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03") and by doin so it seems that its working! Thx for your hint!  2nd issue.. Yes.. I have created a new Thread  Have a great Day! Pete

Answer (score 0):

For your first issue:

It looks like a timing-related issue.

I suggest you make your code wait for some seconds before executing the problematic line of code.

It can help to fetch the value and solve this issue.

For your second issue:

As I informed you in my previous comment, you can create a new thread with detailed information. We will try to check it and try to provide you further suggestions for it.